# ASP.NET NHibernate - failed to lazily initialize a collection no session or session was closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, lazy-loading

I'm having some problems with NHibernate on ASP.NET WebForms Application.

I can do everything - save, get, remove, update register, but when I try to get some objects with a lazy collection, an exception raises:

> Session is closed

I have tried everything. Can someone help?

### RepositoryClass

```
    private ISession m_session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession();

    protected ISession Session
    {
        get
        {
            return m_session;
        }
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            Session.Merge(entity);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    public virtual int Count()
    {
        return (from t in Session.Query<T>()
                select t).Count();
    }

    public virtual void Remove(T entity)
    {
        using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            try
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Delete(entity);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
    }

    public virtual void Remove(int id)
    {
        using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            try
            {
                T entity = session.Get<T>(id);
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Delete(entity);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw new Exception(e.Message);


            }
    }

    public virtual IList<T> ListAll()
    {
        return (from t in Session.Query<T>()
                select t).ToList();
    }

    public virtual T Get(Type entityType, object id)
    {
        return (T)Session.Get(entityType, id);
    }

    public virtual T Get(object id)
    {
        return Session.Get<T>(id);
    }

    public virtual void Save(T entity)
    {
        using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            session.Save(entity);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
```

### NHibernateHelper

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory = null;

    private static ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory()
    {
        return CreateSessionFactory();
    }

    private static Object createLock = new Object();

    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        lock (createLock)
        {

            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {

                Configuration config = new Configuration().Configure(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "Repositorio.hibernate.cfg.xml");
                _sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
            }


            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return GetSessionFactory().OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Comment: the answer is correct but the solution the answer provided is not a good way. you need a Open Session In View pattern. you can search and find lots of things about it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't put my session management in my repos. What is likely occurring is you get a list of items form the repo which opens the session, it then passes the objects back to the controller (page/view or however you have it designed). But by the time the controller gets the items, you have finished the work with the repo and it has closed the session.
In your controller you hit the lazy property, but since the session has been closed, you get the lazy exception. 
For the lazy properties to be available, you need to have the objects attached to a live session until you complete the unit of work. Therefore, you can hit the lazy properties in the repo before handing them off to the controller (kind of defeats the purpose of lazy) or you can put the session control higher up the chain.

I have my http request responsible for the session and use a `RequestHttpModule` to create an active session during the life-cycle for each request (whether I need it or not). That way when the controller of view hits a lazy property, the object is still attached to a live session to get the lazy object.
You could 'Bing' for 'nhibernate session per request' and you will find some blogs detailing the pattern.

My request module looks like:

```
public class RequestHttpModule : IHttpModule {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(ContextBeginRequest);
            context.EndRequest += new EventHandler(ContextEndRequest);
        }

        public void Dispose() { }

        public void ContextBeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
            SessionManager.GetInstance().OpenSession();
        }

        public void ContextEndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
            SessionManager.GetInstance().DisposeCurrentSession();
        }
}
```

Then register the module in the Web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="RequestHttpModule" type="MyWebApp.RequestHttpModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

}